# Getting time for cocos2dx game

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, systemtime

I have a question. I'm developing the game which has lives. The main point is lives can resurrect after each 5 minutes. If I want to make that, I have to get time for algorithm. BUT...

I know many ways to get system time, but the problem is user can change it. So, if some smart user change time, he can get lives sooner than he should. So my question is - how can I avoid this? Is there some functions which returns processor time or how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [time()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/) to get the number of seconds since 00:00 hours, Jan 1, 1970 UTC. I don't know if the user's preference can change the result. Try, but i don't think.

You can see also [clock()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/). This function return the number of tick since program launch. But if you restart your application it's useless...

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it won't work((( I've tried it for the first time(